# Typescript prevent imports from certain directory in project

Tags: typescript, architecture, dependencies

I wonder if there is a way to prevent all files in a certain scope from importing any file from a different second scope. Example:

Given this project structure:

```
project/
├── node_modules/
├── test/
├── src/
│   ├── domain/
│   │   ├── SomeModelClass.ts
│   ├── application/
│   │   ├── SomeApplicationConcern.ts
│   ├── database/
│   │   ├── SomeRepository.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── tslint.json
```

I would like to enforce at least some of these rules:

- `SomeApplicationConcern` can import code from anywhere.
- `SomeRepository` can **not** import code from `application`
- `SomeModelClass` can **not** import code from neither `application` nor `domain`.

Can it be achieved somehow using nested `tsconfig.json` files?
Can it be achieved using some fancy `tslint` rules?

I have no clue if anything like this is possible. I would like to get a compilation error (or tslint error, which is set to *error* severity in my project) if a forbidden dependency is detected.

Comment: Just to let people know, I've settled for good-fences at the time, and don't really have any complaints. The "Dependency Cruiser" suggested by Scotty Jamison looks interesting too, so if you're looking for a solution now, I would suggest you check it out. With good-fences you have to add `fence.json` files in your "modules", so it can take some time to find the correct fence to edit sometimes. The Dependency Cruiser seems to prevent this by using a single file with all the rules. If you only have several rules (highly likely), keeping rules in one places looks better, in my opinion.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A few ideas based on some quick online research:

1. [`good-fences`](https://github.com/smikula/good-fences) is a dedicated tool to restrict imports in a TypeScript project.  You'd have to add it to your build process as a separate step.
2. Compile your TypeScript code with `module` set to `es6` (to a separate output directory if you need a different `module` setting to generate the code you actually run) and then run ESLint with the [`no-restricted-imports` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-imports) on the output.
3. Set up both your runtime environment and your `tsconfig.json` so that you can use only non-relative imports, and then use the `no-relative-imports` rule from [`tslint-microsoft-contrib`](https://github.com/Microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib).  However, there was [talk of deprecating `no-relative-imports`](https://github.com/Microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib/issues/435).
4. Write your own TSLint-based reimplementation of ESLint's `no-restricted-imports` and contribute it to [tslint-eslint-rules](https://github.com/buzinas/tslint-eslint-rules).

Answer (score 17):

It sounds like [Dependency Cruiser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dependency-cruiser) is the tool you're looking for. You can put together any arbitrary rules you want with it, run it during your build process, and it'll automatically report dependency violations. It supports typescript, javascript, commonjs, es6 modules, and more.

I've actually been looking for an answer to this exact question for a while, and it wasn't until recently that I've stumbled upon this tool. Hopefully others can find it useful too.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that the previous answers did not mention is the [`import/no-internal-modules`](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-internal-modules.md) and [`import/no-restricted-paths`](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-restricted-paths.md) ESLint rules.