# TypeScript lint files and folders based on allowing what modules can and cannot be imported

Tags: node.js, typescript, validation, lint

Let's say I'm starting a TypeScript project with a `models`, `views`, and `controllers`. I am interested in adding linting at the file and folder level that states what the rules are for a given folder and file type.

For instance a `view` (any of the TypeScript files within the `views` folder) should never import anything from the `models` folder.

Another example would be that any file within the `routes` folder should be forced to import `express`.

Another example is that all files within `components` should always require `react`.

Here are the relationships I am looking for:

1. should always import
2. should never import
3. should only import

Is this possible within the `TypeScript` or even Node.js ecosystem? Are there any projects that do this?

I'd also like if there was a way to force what type of variable is returned from all the files in a folder, for example all files within `components` should return react components. All files within `json` folder should return `json`.

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52579681) addresses everything except the "should always import".  Do you really need "should always import"?  The consensus of the community seems to be to remove unused imports rather than have a set of files include the same imports for consistency.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I agree with the statement "remove unused imports rather than have a set of files include the same imports" I understand, but the idea is that a `components` folder should not contain any files that do not import `react` not that you'd add an unnecessary import, you'd move the file out of the `components` folder.

Comment: I see.  So you'd create a separate folder for any utility files that are used by `components` but do not themselves contain any React components?  Your web search is as good as mine for whether there's an existing tool that can enforce this or you'd have to develop a new one.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen thanks for your help, https://github.com/smikula/good-fences is a good start!