# Angular lazy-loaded modules with services provideIn this module

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I currently have an issue with lazy laoded modules and services which are `providedIn` this lazy-loaded module.

I have a folder structure looking like this:

*app

-> featureModule1 (lazy loaded)

-> featureModule2 (lazy loaded)

-->services

--->service1.ts*

I want this service1.ts only be available in featureModule2.
So i included @Injectable

```
// service.ts    
@Injectable({
   providedIn: featureModule2
})
export class service1 { /* some logic */ }
```

When i try to route to this lazy loaded module i get an console error:

```
// console    
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Cannot access 'featureModule2' before initialization
    ReferenceError: Cannot access 'featureModule2' before initialization
```

My current lazy load route looks like this:

```
// app-routing.module.ts    
const routes: Routes = [
      {path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'feature1', loadChildren: () => import('./feature1/feature1.module').then(m => m.featureModule1) },
      { path: 'feature2', loadChildren: () => import('./feature2/feature2.module').then(m => m.featureModule2) }
    ];
```

I tried to provide it in the module:

```
// featureModule1     
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
  featureComponent
 ],
 imports: [
   ...
 ],
 providers: [
  service1
 ]
})
```

That doesn't work.

And i tried to import the service1.ts directly a component (`featureComponent`).

```
// featureComponent
import { service1 } from '../featureModule2/services/service1.service';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class featureComponent {
  constructor(private service1: service1) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service1.init();
  }
}
```

This approach lead to the same error message.

The only way to get around this issue at the moment is to create a "wrapper" module which imports all other modules with `@Injectable` services.
Is there a different way for this problem? The services in each module should not be injected in `root` or `any` because they should only be available in each featureModule.

Comment: using `providers` in the module config will work 101%. Why do you say it is not.?

Comment: it works unitl i use lazy loading in the router

Comment: So it works or it does not? You can remove @Injectable and try again.

Comment: No it doesn't work in lazy loaded modules. When i remove @Injectable i can inject the service whereever i want in the app. This is not what i try to achieve.

Comment: This is on older angular, but should be fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s5xxnb-j9ch1z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustomers%2Fcustomers.module.ts

Comment: In my example you can inject it only in the module where it was declared, you cannot do it elsewhere. Works for customers, fails for orders

Answer (score 1):

You just have to declare it in `providers` section and it will work. I have used `useFactory` provider variant in order to clearly show that it is used in order to perform injection and angular is not simply `new LazyService` just in place. I will work with `providers:[LazyService]` as well (which is a 'class provider' I belive, equal to `useClass:LazyService`)

In lazy module

```
import {
  CustomerListComponent,
  LazyService
} from './customer-list/customer-list.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, CustomersRoutingModule],
  declarations: [CustomerListComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: LazyService,
      useFactory: () => new LazyService('proofThatItIsFromPRoviders')
    }
  ]
})
export class CustomersModule {}
```

in lazy component from the same module ("printsLazy service works
proofThatItIsFromPRoviders")

```
export class LazyService {
  constructor(private test: string) {}
  public say() {
    console.log('Lazy service works', this.test);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer-list',
  templateUrl: './customer-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-list.component.css']
})
export class CustomerListComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private lazy: LazyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lazy.say();
  }
}
```

injection in different module fails

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-order-list',
  templateUrl: './order-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order-list.component.css']
})
export class OrderListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private lazy:LazyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lazy.say();
  }

}
```

Working example here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s5xxnb-j9ch1z?file=src%2Fapp%2Forders%2Forder-list%2Forder-list.component.ts

Comment: thats a good way to also lazy load the service inside but in this case it is still possible to inject this service somewhere else in the application.

Comment: My example shows that it is not possible - injection in different module fails at runtime.

Comment: You are absolutly right but if i also provide the lazyService in the orderComponent which is integrated in the orderModule it is possible to inject this service.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s5xxnb-53w6bp?file=src%2Fapp%2Forders%2Forders.module.ts

Comment: Yes, becouse you have "provided" it there - there is nothing strange about it. Angular and typescript does not provide isolation on the code level other than class being NOT exported at all. So you will be able to import it wherever you like. You will end up in multiple instances etc, but you cannot forbid compiler from doing so. Maybe forbiddenImports can do the trick in some case, but then is it worth of trying?

Comment: and right, keep in mind that in your case, you end up with 2 separate instances.

Comment: the two instances are totaly fine in this case.
i work with a big developer team and i want to restrict some injections so the code base keeps maintainable. but i also see the things you are pointing out.
thank you for your examples

Comment: @MrDeibl Two instances are fine, it means that you don't want to share the state. Why use the service then? If accidentally you maintain state, you will end up with bugs difficult to find.

Comment: @RiteshWaghela Because there are many submodules which use the same service with the same state. So for example:
service1 is used by `fModule1.1` `fModule1.2` `fModule1.3`
but must not be used by `fModule2.1` or `fModule2.2`

Comment: @MrDeibl you need something like protected/default access scope like in Java, and there is none available out of the box.  Injections definitions are only a runtime hints while you need compile time guards. Here is probably interesting idea https://stackoverflow.com/a/52582023/1527544

Comment: @Antoniossss thats a good hint thank you very much i will try this.

Answer (score 1):

When we configure a service like this:

```
   @Injectable({
       providedIn: featureModule2
    })
    export class TestService {
    }
```

It means that `TestService` won't be available to applications unless they import featureModule2.

Since  featureModule2 is a lazy loaded module, you definitely not want to specify this in app module imports and hence you will need to either use

```
     @Injectable({
          providedIn: 'any'
      })
      export class TestService {
      }
```

or

```
      @Injectable({
          providedIn: 'root'
      })
      export class TestService {
      }
```

The different between above two is that when we use '`root` there will be a single instance of that service throught the app. In case of '`any`' for lazily loaded module there will be a new instance of that service and for eagerly loaded module it will act as a singleton.

Comment: ok so your answer proved my tests above. So is it the correct way to use a module for lazy-loading and `import` in this module sub modules with restricted services?
featureModule1(lazy) -> import: [featureModule1.1]; service1.ts providesIn: featureModule1.1

Comment: @MrDeibl: We should always provide your service in the root injector unless there is a case where we want that service to be available only if the consumer imports a particular NgModule.

Comment: Yes great thank you and this is what i want to achieve in this case. There are some services which should not be injectable in other modules.

Comment: All such services then should be provided to a specific module using provideIn and then whichever module needs services from this module must import this module.